# get View.php file as JSON object

Tags: php, zend-framework, json

How can I get the view.php file as a json object in Zend framework? Right now I'm using this in controller:

```
// in controller
public function helloAction()
{
    $this->view->meta->title = 'Hello';
    $this->view->meta->keywords = 'hello, wold, freebies';
    $this->view->meta->description = 'Blah blah blah';      
    $this->render();    
}

// in view *hello.php*
<div class="hello">Hello world</div>
```

I want to capture that `hello.php` content in a variable, something like this

```
$html = $this->render();
$this->view->content = $html;
```

so, using this **?render=json** im expecting the results like this

```
[view] => stdClass Object
(
    [meta] => stdClass Object
    (
        [title] => Hello
        [description] => hello, wold, freebies
        [keywords] => Blah blah blah
    )


    [content] => stdClass Object
    (   
        [view] => <div class="hello">Hello world</div>
    )
)
```

how is it possible?

Comment: You're probably looking for http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: @DennisFischer no, I know i can parse it to json but I need the object. view is generating the "Hello world" but I want to hold it in a variable. so that I can parse it to json.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the zend framework [context switch action helpers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.contextswitch)

Example from docs

```
class NewsController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function init()
    {
        $contextSwitch = $this->_helper->getHelper('contextSwitch');
        $contextSwitch->addActionContext('list', 'xml')
                      ->initContext();
    }

    // ...
}
```